# How to solve Xamarin forms Amazon AWSSDK error in iOS while linker is enabled?

Tags: amazon-s3, linker, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I've integrated the xamarin forms AWSSDK S3 which is working fine in Android with linker enabled but not working in iOS while linker is enabled. I'm getting the below error

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error Failed to resolve "System.Void Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.AESEncryptionPutObjectStream::.ctor(System.IO.Stream,System.Byte[],System.Byte[])" reference from "AWSSDK.Core, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604"
```

I've tried it in a fresh project but it works fine in that. I've update the nuget packages also but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by updating the PCLCrypto package installed with AWSSDK. It worked :)